# Why is minValue inclusive, but maxValue exclusive for Random.Next()?

Tags: c#, random

This is sort of weird to me. I'm sure I'll get used to it soon enough, but I just want to know why it's made like that.

Answer (score 6):

Reason 1) `maxValue - minValue` gives the number of possible items in the range, so you can use code like this:

```
var randomItemFromArray = MyArray[random.Next(0, MyArray.Length)];
```

To do this if the upper bound was inclusive would look a little clunky/odd.

Reason 2) It is easier to code

Reason 3) It ensures an even spread of possibilities when using a floating point -

See [Exclusive upper bound in random number range](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/311250/exclusive-upper-bound-in-random-number-range/311253) for more info

Answer (score 4):

Imagine that you have several ranges, e.g.

- Starts from 0
- Starts from 100   (range of interest)
- Starts from 500   (next range)
- Starts from 1000

and we have to get a random value from 2nd range, all we should do

```
random.Next(100, 500);
```

i.e. 1st argument is the range start and the 2nd is the *next* range start;
it's very convenient if the range is *complex*: all we have to know where each 
range starts (we have no need to compute *exact inclusive upper border*, but can say "up, but not including the next range"). E.g. we want to get random moment (up to second) in February 2016:

```
DateTime start     = new DateTime(2016, 2, 1);
// Please notice how much easier it is to put "1 Mar" than "29 Feb 23:59:59"
DateTime startNext = new DateTime(2016, 3, 1);

// Please notice: just subtraction
DateTime random = start + 
  TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next((startNext - start).TotalSeconds));
```